# Wiring new dimmer to 3 black wires

Tags: lighting, dimmer-switch

Trying to replace a single switch w a dimmer w 4 wires. The old switch had 2 blacks pushed in the back and one black on a side screw.  It only works a chandelier and not on any wall plugs in the rm.  Seems to have its own supply. One of the wires must lead to/from another room w two lights.  I can get the chandelier to light but not the lights in the other room or vice versa. I have tried all different combinations of connections but haven’t dared connect any 2 black wires together.

Comment: Picture of wires? Model of new dimmer?

Comment: Include the pictures you took before disconnecting everything.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, and now other things in your house are dead.

First, you'll need to work with the 3 black wires.  Normally experimentation is *dangerous*, but it's OK with a group of non-ground wires that previously went to a switch.

With wire nuts, nut black wires #1 and #2 *to each other* and cap off #3.  Turn the main breaker back on and test the circuit. You'll get one of three outcomes:

- everything is still dead
- the light lights up, but the other stuff is still dead
- the other stuff now works and the lamp is dead.

The 3rd case is the one we're looking for.  There, the solo wire is the **switched-hot** to the lamp.  If you happen to have red electrical tape, spiraling it around this wire is a good move.

Now you wire up the switch with "line side hot" to the 2 hot wires (which are **always-hot**), and the "Load side hot" to the solo we might've just marked red.

As far as the other 2 wires, follow the instructions.   By all the blacks going to this switch, I gather those are in cables that also have white wires and those are indeed neutral.